# GUI for cross platform

Tags: java, user-interface, cross-platform

I need to make application for calculating some parameters for Network. So I need to make GUI where user can design own network. For example draw rooters (to do this user need to select icon for rooter and then place rooter on sketch), define some parameters for rooter, than draw line (that represent link between rooters) and define parameter for link. This is all. What you suggest me to use for this purpose?

Comment: Have you tried Swing?

Comment: Which platforms are you aiming for? UI for mobile, touch-capable devices have different paradigms than UI for desktop or laptop computers.

Comment: I make UI for linux desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Java, I suggest you to use Swing or Java FX: both Java-based and of course, platform-independent..